# How may I convert this JSON into CSV?

Tags: csv, json, jq

I have below JSON document to convert into CSV. I need to iterate over the first column with the 2nd and 3rd (they can be either string or array) at the same time as one iteration.

Example document:

```json
[
  {
    "results": [
       [
        "abc025",
        "true",
        "test.lun"
      ],
       [
        "xyz025",
        [
          "true",
          "false",
          "true"
        ],
        [
          "product.lun",
          "app.lun",
          "ora.lun"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected CSV:

```
"abc025","true","test.lun"
"xyz025","true","product.lun"
"xyz025","false","app.lun"
"xyz025","true","ora.lun"
```

Comment: sure, this one has more than 1 array, also I'd like to learn how to iterate the first string with the 2nd and 3rd array at the same index, the expected output shows the different logic from the last one.  thanks

Comment: Are the values in the `xyz025` array really unquoted, and you want them quoted?  There is a big difference between `false` (a boolean) and `"false"` (a string) in JSON.

Comment: yes I will edit the post

Comment: this is so the farest I could go, but got xyz025 missing on the 2nd and 3rd rows.  '.[].results[] | [ [ .[0][]? // .[0] ], [ .[1][]? // .[1] ], [ .[2][]? // .[2] ] ] | to_entries | (map(.value) | transpose[]) | @csv'

Comment: thanks for the update, please also [edit] your question to add your reply in comments into body of the question you have,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `jq` expression

```
.[].results[] | .[0] as $name | .[1:] | map([.[]]? // [.]) |
(.[0]|keys[]) as $i | [ $name, .[][$i] ] | @csv
```

The first line here picks out `$name` as the first element (`.[0]`) from each individual sub-array (`abc025` and `xyz025` respectively, in separate iterations) and then transforms the remaining data in each sub-array (`.[1:]`) into arrays of one array per column:

```json
[["true"],["test.lun"]]
[["true","false","true"],["product.lun","app.lun","ora.lun"]]
```

This is done in the `map()` call where each element is extracted as an array. If that does not work, the element is *put into* an array. So each element either remains an array, or is converted into a single element array.

The second line iterates over the indexes of these column arrays and creates the output as CSV.

Testing:

```
$ jq -r '.[].results[] | .[0] as $name | .[1:] | map([.[]]? // [.]) | (.[0]|keys[]) as $i | [ $name, .[][$i] ] | @csv' file
"abc025","true","test.lun"
"xyz025","true","product.lun"
"xyz025","false","app.lun"
"xyz025","true","ora.lun"
```

Note that this is a generalization of [my solution to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665456/116858).  You may use this code with your data from that question too.

You may also use this on data with more than three columns. The document

```json
[
  {
    "results": [
      [ "abc025",
        "true",
        "test.lun",
        "blueberry" ],
      [ "xyz025",
        ["true","false","true"],
        ["product.lun","app.lun","ora.lun"],
        ["strawberry","cloudberry","lingonberry"] ]
    ]
  }
]
```

would convert into

```
"abc025","true","test.lun","blueberry"
"xyz025","true","product.lun","strawberry"
"xyz025","false","app.lun","cloudberry"
"xyz025","true","ora.lun","lingonberry"
```